# Android Jetpack Compose align row to start

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to replicate the following (it's a course on Android Basics offered by Google):

[basic-android-kotlin-compose-business-card png](https://developer.android.com/static/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-business-card/img/c941a07bca72427f_856.png)

My latest code is as follows:

```kotlin
package com.example.businesscard

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.Call
import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.Email
import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.Share
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.businesscard.ui.theme.BusinessCardTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BusinessCardTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    PresentationApp()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PresentationHeader(
    imagePainter: Painter,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier.background(Color.DarkGray)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = imagePainter,
                contentDescription = stringResource(
                    R.string.business_card_header_image_content_description
                ),
                modifier = modifier
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .width(100.dp)
            )
        }
        Text(
            text = name,
            fontSize = 36.sp,
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(bottom=4.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = description,
            color = Color(0xFF3DDC84),
            modifier = modifier
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun PresentationTextWithIcon(
    imageVector: ImageVector,
    imageString: String,
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
    ) {
        Row {
            Icon(imageVector, imageString)
            Spacer(modifier.width(16.dp))
            Text(
                text = text,
                color = Color(0xFF3DDC84),
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PresentationFooter(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val appIcons = Icons.Rounded

    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(bottom = 26.dp)
    ) {
        PresentationTextWithIcon(
            imageVector = appIcons.Call,
            imageString = stringResource(
                R.string.presentation_footer_call_icon_text
            ),
            text = stringResource(
                R.string.presentation_footer_phone_number
            )
        )
        Spacer(Modifier.height(10.dp))
        PresentationTextWithIcon(
            imageVector = appIcons.Share,
            imageString = stringResource(
                R.string.presentation_footer_share_icon_text
            ),
            text = stringResource(
                R.string.presentation_footer_social_media
            )
        )
        Spacer(Modifier.height(10.dp))
        PresentationTextWithIcon(
            imageVector = appIcons.Email,
            imageString = stringResource(
                R.string.presentation_footer_email_icon_text
            ),
            text = stringResource(
                R.string.presentation_footer_email_address
            )
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun PresentationApp() {
    PresentationHeader(
        imagePainter = painterResource(R.drawable.android_logo),
        name = stringResource(R.string.business_card_person_name),
        description = stringResource(R.string.business_card_person_title)
    )
    PresentationFooter()
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PresentationAppPreview() {
    BusinessCardTheme {
        PresentationApp()
    }
}
```

however, what I'm getting is:

[row composable fails to align to start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmqt2.png)

as you can see, the second Row element with share icon and "@AndroidDev" text is not aligned with the others at the start.

I've tried various solutions and the one I arrived at that does the job is:

https://github.com/alghe-global/Kotlin/commit/870608e4a3e04a1f0112f7039e7194c9686279d3#diff-1906f799db6610a6602eda36437532f49f619ab495689e07a871c2f631bdb951

however, as you can see, on line #118, there is this `Space` that aligns the Row Column at the "center" of the screen

```kotlin
        Spacer(modifier.width(75.dp))  // XXX: pretty bad solution to center footer
```

which is something I'd like to get rid of (hence my latest code at the beginning of this thread that tries to do it without the above `Spacer`).

Any ideas on how to align the multiple `PresentationTextWithIcon` all at the `Start` of `Column` while keeping those multiple `PresentationTextWithIcon` vertically arranged to the bottom of the screen and horizontally aligned to the center?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding

```kotlin
Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
        ) {
```

to all the `PresentationTextWithIcon` Composables:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PresentationFooter(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val appIcons = Icons.Rounded

    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(bottom=40.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
        ) {
            PresentationTextWithIcon(
                imageVector = appIcons.Call,
                imageString = stringResource(
                    R.string.presentation_footer_call_icon_text
                ),
                text = stringResource(
                    R.string.presentation_footer_phone_number
                )
            )
            Spacer(Modifier.height(10.dp))
            PresentationTextWithIcon(
                imageVector = appIcons.Share,
                imageString = stringResource(
                    R.string.presentation_footer_share_icon_text
                ),
                text = stringResource(
                    R.string.presentation_footer_social_media
                )
            )
            Spacer(Modifier.height(10.dp))
            PresentationTextWithIcon(
                imageVector = appIcons.Email,
                imageString = stringResource(
                    R.string.presentation_footer_email_icon_text
                ),
                text = stringResource(
                    R.string.presentation_footer_email_address
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```